# Apache Rampart WS-Security: one client, several service instances

Tags: java, soap, mutual-authentication, wss4j, rampart

I'm adding X.509 Mutual Certificate authentication into the project. The specific case here is that one client (let's say `manager`) can access several service instances (`servers`). Each `server` has its own certificate. When providing a `policy.xml` configuration on client side `<encryptionUser>` should be set to server's alias certificate stored in client's trustore. It's not a problem when the `server` is only one but when client need to access specific `server`, an appropriate `server`'s public key should be used for encryption so I need to provide a proper alias from the truststore.
I was thinking to programmarically change Rampart configuration on each request to set a specific alias name but this looks like not a proper way to do.
I'm looking for a standard approach here or, perhaps, some way to configure that in `policy.xml`
My client's (`manager`'s) Rampart configuration part from `policy.xml` is below

```
<ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
   <ramp:userCertAlias>client</ramp:userCertAlias>
   <!-- This should be dynamic -->
   <ramp:encryptionUser>server</ramp:encryptionUser>
   <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>PasswordProvider</ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
   <ramp:signatureCrypto>
       <ramp:crypto provider="MerlinCrypto"/>
   </ramp:signatureCrypto>
   <ramp:encryptionCrypto>
       <ramp:crypto provider="MerlinCrypto"/>
   </ramp:encryptionCrypto>
</ramp:RampartConfig>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was resolved by programmatically setting `encryptionUser` parameter to already parsed and built (from `policy.xml`) `RampartConfig` object inside `Policy` object.
Build `Policy` object from configuration file, then go through the `Assertion`s, find `RamparConfig` object among them and set the property.

```
String encrUser = "myEncrUser";
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("policy.xml")) {
    OMXMLParserWrapper omBuilder = OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(is);
    Policy policy = PolicyEngine.getPolicy(omBuilder.getDocumentElement());
    for (Iterator<List<Assertion>> assrItr = policy.getAlternatives(); assrItr.hasNext(); ) {
        List<Assertion> assr = assertionsIterator.next();
        assr.stream().filter(RampartConfig.class::isInstance)
            .findFirst().map(RampartConfig.class::cast)
            .ifPresent(cfg -> cfg.setEncryptionUser(encrUser));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Here a client application needs to have axis2 client object configured for each service but that was fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your current encryptionUser

```
<ramp:encryptionUser>server</ramp:encryptionUser>
```

with

```
<ramp:encryptionUser>useReqSigCert</ramp:encryptionUser>
```

Then the certificate used to sign the request message will be automatically used to encrypt the response message

[Source](http://axis.8716.n7.nabble.com/Axis2-rampart-encryption-and-multiple-clients-td34873.html)

Comment: Hi @rekotc, thanks for your answer. The usage of `useReqSigCert` does work for one server several clients approach. So when you set it to the server's `policy.xml` Rampart uses signature from client SOAP message to encrypt the response. But it does not work when you have several service instances (with several identity certificates) - at least I didn't get how to achieve that using configuration only :)

Comment: Hi @sys463, you are right, i misunderstood your problem! Now i'd like to ask you a more detailed solution to your problem, as i might find myself in this situation... :D

Comment: Hi @rekotc! I've updated the answer with some code examples. It's not ideal, but that's what I came to :)